# SQL Server to count how many times a value appears between multiple date ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a table with two columns in question.

- Column A - timestamp
- Column B - EmpID

What I'm trying to do is to compare weeks to see how many times an EmpID has repeated.  For example:

Week1 is my base (starting date range e.g. BETWEEN '2017-07-22' AND '2017-07-29 23:59:59.993'). I now want to compare week2 against week1.  If an EmpID repeats in week2 I was to see a count of 2 and if it appears for the first time in week2 then a count of 1.

Moving on to week3. If the EmpID appears in week1, week2 and week3 then I want to see a count of 3, if it only appears in week2 and week3 then a count of 2 and if it only appears in week3 then a count of 1.

And finally for week4. If the EmpID appears in week1, week2, week3 and week4 then I want to see a count of 4. If the EmpID appears in week2, week3 and week4 then a count of 3, if it appears in week3 and week4 then a count of 2 and if it only appears for the first time in week4 then a count of 1.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

Added what I've tried so far but not getting the desired results.

```
select t.emp_id,
(select count(emp_id) 
from [Vacation Audit Care 2017]
WHERE ((UPLOAD_DATE BETWEEN '2017-07-22' AND '2017-07-29 23:59:59.993') or(UPLOAD_DATE BETWEEN '2017-07-29' AND '2017-08-05 23:59:59.993') or (UPLOAD_DATE BETWEEN '2017-08-12' AND '2017-08-19 23:59:59.993'))
and emp_id=t.emp_id) as counts
from [Vacation Audit Care 2017] t
group by t.emp_id
order by counts desc
```

sample data

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════╗
║ Time_Stamp      ║ Emp_ID  ║
║ 7/20/2017 19:40 ║ 3140340 ║
║ 7/20/2017 19:40 ║ 2000950 ║
║ 7/20/2017 19:40 ║ 3118410 ║
║ 7/20/2017 19:40 ║ 311840  ║
║ 7/23/2017 21:19 ║ 3140340 ║
║ 7/23/2017 21:19 ║ 2000950 ║
║ 7/23/2017 21:19 ║ 3118410 ║
║ 7/23/2017 21:19 ║ 3124160 ║
║ 7/30/2017 7:00  ║ 3140340 ║
║ 7/30/2017 7:00  ║ 2000950 ║
║ 7/30/2017 7:00  ║ 3118410 ║
║ 7/30/2017 7:00  ║ 311840  ║
║ 8/6/2017 12:00  ║ 3140340 ║
║ 8/6/2017 12:00  ║ 3118410 ║
║ 8/6/2017 12:00  ║ 3124160 ║
║ 8/6/2017 12:00  ║ 311840  ║
║ 8/13/2017 12:00 ║ 3140340 ║
║ 8/13/2017 12:00 ║ 3118410 ║
║ 8/13/2017 12:00 ║ 3124160 ║
║ 8/13/2017 12:00 ║ 311840  ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════╝
```

Expected output

```
╔═════════╦════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║         ║ 30-Jul ║ 6-Aug ║ 13-Aug ║
║ emp_id  ║ wk2    ║ wk3   ║ wk4    ║
║ 3140340 ║ 2      ║ 3     ║ 4      ║
║ 2000950 ║ 2      ║       ║        ║
║ 3118410 ║ 2      ║ 3     ║ 4      ║
║ 311840  ║ 1      ║ 2     ║ 3      ║
║ 3124160 ║        ║ 1     ║ 2      ║
╚═════════╩════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

As per the expected output using 7/23 as my base (week1)
the table shows the expected data results.
In week2 311840 appears for the first time so I expect a count of 1.

The following week (8/6) 311840 appears once in wk2 and once in wk3 so I expect a count of 2 while 3124160 appears for the first time so I expect a count of 1 etc.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Tarheel, I've added some sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give results in the format that you show in your sample. I've included an extra week before and after in the output. To remove those extra weeks just remove [29] and [33] from the pivot. Comment out the pivot line to just get the underlying data.

```
;WITH 
weekcounts AS (
    SELECT Time_Stamp, Emp_ID, DATEPART(week, Time_Stamp) AS int_week FROM sampleData
)

,counts AS (
    SELECT Emp_ID, int_week, 1 AS int_count
    FROM weekcounts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT weekcounts.Emp_ID, weekcounts.int_week, 1 AS int_count
    FROM weekcounts
        INNER JOIN counts
            ON weekcounts.Emp_ID = counts.Emp_ID
            AND (weekcounts.int_week - 1) = counts.int_week
)

,countsagg AS (
    SELECT Emp_ID, int_week, SUM(int_count) AS int_count
    FROM counts
    GROUP BY Emp_ID, int_week
)

SELECT * FROM countsagg
PIVOT (MAX(int_count) FOR int_week IN ([29],[30],[31],[32],[33])) piv
```

Comment: Oh my gosh David, this is exactly what I was looking for - much appreciated and thanks for your time.

Comment: Unsung Hero award :)

Comment: Hi David, not sure if this is appropriate or not and I must apologize in advance if it's inappropriate - I've posted a required modification at the below URL - since it's technically not the same question but very similar I'm wondering if you can help me out with the modifications.<b>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719415/sql-server-to-count-how-many-times-a-value-appears-between-multiple-date-ranges</b>

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP]) AS [ROWCOUNT]
   ,DATENAME(WEEK, timestamp) weeknum
   INTO #TMPweek
  FROM [Vacation Audit Care 2017]
  where timestamp>'2017-07-20 19:40:00.000'

   select distinct timestamp,  cast(day(timestamp) as nvarchar)+
   cast('-' as nvarchar)+cast(datename(m,[timestamp]) as nvarchar)+
   cast(' wk' as nvarchar) +cast(DATEPART(wk, timestamp) as nvarchar) weekname
   into #tw from #TMPweek

  select empid,[ROWCOUNT], weekname into #pvt
  from
  #TMPweek a
  inner join #tw b
  on a.timestamp=b.timestamp

  SELECT  empid, [23-July wk30], [30-July wk31], [6-August wk32], [13-August 
  wk33]
  FROM 
  (select empid,[ROWCOUNT], Weekname from #pvt
   ) AS ST
  PIVOT
  (
  SUM([ROWCOUNT])
  FOR Weekname IN ([23-July wk30], [30-July wk31], [6-August wk32], [13-August 
  wk33])
  ) AS PivotTable;

  OUTPUT -
  empid 23-July wk30    30-July wk31    6-August wk32   13-August wk33
  311840    NULL    1   2   3
  2000950   1   2   NULL    NULL
  3118410   1   2   3   4
  3124160   1   NULL    2   3
  3140340   1   2   3   4
```

Comment: Thanks piyush for you assistance.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
SET DATEFIRST 1; --this will set Monday as first day of week.
SELECT EmpID, count(1)
from table
group by DATEPART(wk, timestamp), EmpID
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me and returned a count of 1 for all emp_id

Comment: My solution works, the problem is that SQL starts the week on sundays, so for example with your dataset Emp_id 2000950 who worked on 7/20, 7/23 and 7/30 worked on 3 different weeks, and thus shows 1 count on each week. Try with a more 'complete' dataset (several rows per week per EmpID) and you'll see. You want to count weeks from monday to monday?

Comment: Thanks Vallo, I do see the counts for each week but my expected result is by week 2 I should see a count of 2 (instead of 1) meaning that the emp_id appeared in both weeks and by the 3rd week I should see a count of 3 as it appeared in all 3 weeks.  So some how I looking for a sum of the counts if there appear in multiple weeks.

Comment: I've added a query in your edited answer that did not give the expected results if I specify a timeframe

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. it should work. I believe you want to group the weeks per month.

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEV)/7 * 7)/7 + 1,DATEPART(M, DATEV),EMPID,COUNT(1) 
FROM #GB 
GROUP BY
DATEPART(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEV)/7 * 7)/7 + 1,DATEPART(M, DATEV),EMPID
```

Comment: Thanks Santhosh, Just as with Vallo's help when I also specified a timeframe I'm not seeing the expected results.  I've added an example of the query to your answer and the result is just a count of 1 for each week

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the sample data, made the question much clearer and definitely more useful for other folks as they visit this question in the future.

**Sample Data Setup:**

For the sake of ease, I popped your sample data into a [table variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql) as defined and populated below.

```
declare @emp_ts table
    (
        time_stamp datetime not null
        , emp_id int not null
    )

insert into @emp_ts 
values ('7/20/2017 19:40', 3140340),
('7/20/2017 19:40', 2000950),
('7/20/2017 19:40', 3118410),
('7/20/2017 19:40', 311840 ),
('7/23/2017 21:19', 3140340),
('7/23/2017 21:19', 2000950),
('7/23/2017 21:19', 3118410),
('7/23/2017 21:19', 3124160),
('7/30/2017 7:00 ', 3140340),
('7/30/2017 7:00 ', 2000950),
('7/30/2017 7:00 ', 3118410),
('7/30/2017 7:00 ', 311840 ),
('8/6/2017 12:00 ', 3140340),
('8/6/2017 12:00 ', 3118410),
('8/6/2017 12:00 ', 3124160),
('8/6/2017 12:00 ', 311840 ),
('8/13/2017 12:00', 3140340),
('8/13/2017 12:00', 3118410),
('8/13/2017 12:00', 3124160),
('8/13/2017 12:00', 311840 )
```

**Answer:**

I used a [Recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to generate the week numbers, and then made use of a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) to get the running total count of each `emp_id` as the weeks went on. Took the results of that and [pivoted](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) it out to get the weeks expected in the expected format. You could concatenate the date into the column name, but I figure the column names provided will work.

```
; with wk_nbrs as
    (
        --recursive CTE that generates the week numbers.
        -- 7/23 thru 7/29 is Week 1
        select cast('2017-07-23' as date) as wk_bgn
        , cast('2017-07-29' as date) as wk_end
        , 1 as wk_nbr
        union all
        select dateadd(d,7,fw.wk_bgn) as wk_bgn
        , dateadd(d,7,fw.wk_end) as wk_end
        , fw.wk_nbr + 1 as wk_nbr
        from wk_nbrs as fw
        where 1=1
        and fw.wk_nbr < 100
    )
    , emp_wk_cnt as
    (
        --Getting the running total count of emp_id by week
        select a.emp_id
        , b.wk_nbr
        , count(*) over (partition by a.emp_id order by b.wk_nbr asc) as emp_wk_cnt
        from @emp_ts as a
        inner join wk_nbrs as b on cast(a.time_stamp as date) between b.wk_bgn and b.wk_end
        group by a.emp_id
        , b.wk_nbr  
    )
--pivoting the results out to final expected output
select post.emp_id
, post.wk2
, post.wk3
, post.wk4
from (
    select a.emp_id
    , 'wk' + cast(a.wk_nbr as varchar(10)) as wk_nbr
    , a.emp_wk_cnt
    from emp_wk_cnt as a
    ) as pre
pivot (sum(pre.emp_wk_cnt) 
        for pre.wk_nbr in 
            ([wk2],[wk3],[wk4])
    ) post
order by post.emp_id
```

**Results:**

The results of the query are below. The only difference between your expected output and the blow is for `emp_id` 3124160 which I believe should be 2 in wk3 and 3 in wk 4 because the `emp_id` in question has a record with the following `time_stamp`s:

```
7/23/2017 21:19
8/6/2017 12:00
8/13/2017 12:00
```

Let me know if that's not the case.

```
emp_id    wk2  wk3  wk4
311840     1    2    3
2000950    2    
3118410    2    3    4
3124160         2    3
3140340    2    3    4
```

Comment: Thanks tarheel, along with David both your solutions works well for me - much appreciate your efforts and explanation.

Comment: Hi Tarheel, not sure if this is appropriate or not and I must apologize in advance if it's inappropriate - I've posted a required modification at the below URL - since it's technically not the same question but very similar I'm wondering if you can help me with the modifications. <b>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719415/sql-server-to-count-how-many-times-a-value-appears-between-multiple-date-ranges</b>