# SQL Server to count how many times a value appears between multiple date ranges and compare to previous weeks

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I first asked a similar question at

**[SQL Server to count how many times a value appears between multiple date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679333/sql-server-to-count-how-many-times-a-value-appears-between-multiple-date-ranges/45700266#45700266)**

and wasn't sure if I should post a new question or modify the original post.  Though it's building on the original post I felt it was different enough to render a new post - please advise if this was the correct thing to do.

I wasn't given a few solutions that worked well but unfortunately a caveat was thrown at me and I need to make some modifications based on an additional criteria and not able to solve it.

First off here again are some sample data and the expected output

```
|   Time_Stamp    | Emp_ID  | Balance | Hours |
|-----------------|---------|---------|-------|
| 7/16/2017 19:40 | 3140340 |    2250 |  37.5 |
| 7/16/2017 19:40 | 2000950 |    4050 |  67.5 |
| 7/16/2017 19:40 | 3118410 |     400 |   6.7 |
| 7/16/2017 19:40 |  311840 |   11700 |   195 |
| 7/23/2017 21:19 | 3140340 |    2250 |  37.5 |
| 7/23/2017 21:19 | 2000950 |    4050 |  67.5 |
| 7/23/2017 21:19 | 3118410 |     800 |  13.3 |
| 7/23/2017 21:19 | 3124160 |     450 |   7.5 |
| 7/23/2017 21:19 |  311840 |     400 |   6.7 |
| 7/30/2017 7:00  | 3140340 |    2250 |  37.5 |
| 7/30/2017 7:00  | 2000950 |     400 |   6.7 |
| 7/30/2017 7:00  | 3118410 |    1200 |    20 |
| 7/30/2017 7:00  |  311840 |     700 |  11.7 |
| 8/6/2017 12:00  | 3140340 |     444 |   7.4 |
| 8/6/2017 12:00  | 3118410 |     444 |   7.4 |
| 8/6/2017 12:00  | 3124160 |      90 |   1.5 |
| 8/6/2017 12:00  |  311840 |     325 |   5.4 |
| 8/13/2017 12:00 | 3140340 |     900 |    15 |
| 8/13/2017 12:00 | 3118410 |    1350 |  22.5 |
| 8/13/2017 12:00 | 3124160 |      90 |   1.5 |
| 8/13/2017 12:00 |  311840 |    1700 |  28.3 |
```

Expected output is as follows

```
|         | 16-Jul | 23-Jul | 30-Jul | 6-Aug | 13-Aug |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|-------|--------|
| emp_id  | wk1    | wk2    | wk3    | wk4   | wk5    |
| 3140340 | 1      | 2      | 3      | 0     | 1      |
| 2000950 | 1      | 2      | 0      | 0     | 0      |
| 3118410 | 0      | 1      | 2      | 0     | 1      |
| 311840  | 1      | 0      | 1      | 0     | 1      |
| 3124160 | 0      | 1      | 0      | 1     | 2      |
```

An important note - unfortunately the data type for balance (minutes) is in varchar and I need to convert it to hours by dividing by 60.  I used the following for that

```
ROUND(CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(float,([BALANCE]/convert(float,60.0)))),2) AS [Hours]
```

With that being said what I now need to accomplish is if the balance of each week is less than 7.5 hours then just put a 0 (zero).

If it is >= 7.5 hours then a count of 1.  If consecutive weeks are >= 7.5 hours - for example 2 consecutive weeks then the first week will have a count of 1 and the 2nd week a count of 2.  IF the 3rd week is below 7.5 hours then 0.

As stated earlier the original question along with the solutions can be found at
**[SQL Server to count how many times a value appears between multiple date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679333/sql-server-to-count-how-many-times-a-value-appears-between-multiple-date-ranges/45700266#45700266)**

Two of the solutions that worked really well for the original question were

```
;WITH 
weekcounts AS (
SELECT Time_Stamp, Emp_ID, DATEPART(week, Time_Stamp) AS int_week FROM sampleData
)

,counts AS (
SELECT Emp_ID, int_week, 1 AS int_count
FROM weekcounts
UNION ALL
SELECT weekcounts.Emp_ID, weekcounts.int_week, 1 AS int_count
FROM weekcounts
    INNER JOIN counts
        ON weekcounts.Emp_ID = counts.Emp_ID
        AND (weekcounts.int_week - 1) = counts.int_week
)

,countsagg AS (
SELECT Emp_ID, int_week, SUM(int_count) AS int_count
FROM counts
GROUP BY Emp_ID, int_week
)

SELECT * FROM countsagg
PIVOT (MAX(int_count) FOR int_week IN ([29],[30],[31],[32],[33])) piv
```

and

```
; with wk_nbrs as
(
    --recursive CTE that generates the week numbers.
    -- 7/23 thru 7/29 is Week 1
    select cast('2017-07-23' as date) as wk_bgn
    , cast('2017-07-29' as date) as wk_end
    , 1 as wk_nbr
    union all
    select dateadd(d,7,fw.wk_bgn) as wk_bgn
    , dateadd(d,7,fw.wk_end) as wk_end
    , fw.wk_nbr + 1 as wk_nbr
    from wk_nbrs as fw
    where 1=1
    and fw.wk_nbr < 100
)
, emp_wk_cnt as
(
    --Getting the running total count of emp_id by week
    select a.emp_id
    , b.wk_nbr
    , count(*) over (partition by a.emp_id order by b.wk_nbr asc) as emp_wk_cnt
    from @emp_ts as a
    inner join wk_nbrs as b on cast(a.time_stamp as date) between b.wk_bgn and b.wk_end
    group by a.emp_id
    , b.wk_nbr  
)
--pivoting the results out to final expected output
select post.emp_id
, post.wk2
, post.wk3
, post.wk4
from (
select a.emp_id
, 'wk' + cast(a.wk_nbr as varchar(10)) as wk_nbr
, a.emp_wk_cnt
from emp_wk_cnt as a
) as pre
pivot (sum(pre.emp_wk_cnt) 
    for pre.wk_nbr in 
        ([wk2],[wk3],[wk4])
) post
order by post.emp_id
```

Any additional assistance with this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might give you what you are looking for:

```
;WITH 
weekcounts AS (
    SELECT Time_Stamp, Emp_ID, [Balance], ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT,[Balance]) / 60.0,2) AS [Hours], DATEPART(week, Time_Stamp) AS int_week FROM newSampleData
)

,counts AS (
    SELECT Emp_ID, int_week, 1 AS int_count
    FROM weekcounts
    WHERE ([Hours] >= 7.5)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT weekcounts.Emp_ID, weekcounts.int_week, 1 AS int_count
    FROM weekcounts
        INNER JOIN counts
            ON weekcounts.Emp_ID = counts.Emp_ID
            AND (weekcounts.int_week - 1) = counts.int_week
            AND ([Hours] >= 7.5)
)

,countsagg AS (
    SELECT Emp_ID, int_week, SUM(int_count) AS int_count
    FROM counts
    GROUP BY Emp_ID, int_week
)

SELECT Emp_ID, 
       ISNULL([29],0) AS [week 29],
       ISNULL([30],0) AS [week 30],
       ISNULL([31],0) AS [week 31],
       ISNULL([32],0) AS [week 32],
       ISNULL([33],0) AS [week 33] 
FROM countsagg
PIVOT (MAX(int_count) FOR int_week IN ([29],[30],[31],[32],[33])) piv
```

Also if Balance is a varchar you are doing more converts than needed in your code provided. This will give the result for hours with less code:

```
ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT,[Balance]) / 60.0,2)
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help David.  You are awesome!!...  Also the tip for converting the balance from varchar and great.  Can't say thank you enough.

Comment: Hi David,  I just noticed an error on my part - if I have a missing week or choose not to include a week I will still like it to continue the count.  Meaning week 30 count of 1, week 31 count of 2 and week 33 count of 3 (note how I omitted week 32). If the week is included back it will continue as per normal.  I wasn't aware that there are times certain weeks are not counted.